# Can I use AWS named profiles without placing them in a credentials file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, credentials

Is it possible to create a named profile without creating a credentials file?

For example, storing the profile in path variables?

Comment: What is it that you're actually trying to do here that makes you think of configuring a complete credentials profile in environment variables? Also note: depending on your choice of AWS SDKs, you may be able to write a custom credentials provider to retrieve credentials from anywhere you choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, this is not possible.**

You can pass information like the `aws_access_key_id` & `aws_secret_access_key` via the CLI or store them in path variables using `export` but for them to persist & be grouped under a *name*, they must be stored *somewhere*.

That *somewhere* must be a `credentials` or `config` file.